# regular expression xss

Tags: php, regex

I'm working on a simple project to teach about XSS. I'm trying to make a regex that will catch
`<script>alert('anything')</script>;`

I crafted: `<script>alert\(\'[\w!@#$%^&*()-=+]+\'\);</script>` but when i try to implement it in php I get errors yet when I try it in a regex tool it says it matches my string.

Anyone know how to make a regex that works?

Thanks

Comment: Working in which sense? Offer protection or give you the false feeling that you're protected?

Comment: @NeverHopeless: If you really think we need a [tag:regex-php] tag, go ahead and add it.  But STOP REMOVING THE [tag:regex] TAG!  And the same goes for [tag:regex-asp.net] and whatever other flavors/platforms you're thinking about creating.  Any change as sweeping and disruptive as this should go through some kind of peer review first.

Comment: @AlanMoore, ok. do i need to rollback those questions for the regex tag as well ?

Comment: @NeverHopeless - I've rolled back some of them, but as Alan said, please stop doing this. Removing the more appropriate, broader tags makes these questions much less visible. Focus on making broader improvements to the posts beyond simply inserting tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess it is because you aren't escaping some of the characters in your expression. I think the following regex should work for you:

```
 /\<script\>.*\<\/script\>;/
```

The following metacharacters are supposed to be escaped in regex:

```
^ [ . $ { * ( \ + ) | + ) < >
```

Like:

```
\^ \[ \. \$ \{ \* \( \\ \+ \) \| \+ \) \< \>
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. `/\<script\>alert\("[\w!@#$%^&*\(\)-=+]+"\);\<\/script\>/` works

Comment: Since you are new and this appears to be your first question, I would encourage you to accept the answer that works the best for your needs. Thank you

Comment: I would except your answer right away but it takes a few moments before the site will allow an answer to be accepted. Thank you for your help but relax.

Answer (score 2):

Using regular expressions is not the way to secure against cross-site scripting.

There are several effective means of doing so. [This article](http://joshduck.com/blog/2008/04/05/securing-your-php-code-xss/) discusses the most basic protections. Typically, one should know what sort of input the user should be providing, and use the [Filter](http://php.net/filter) extension to either validate it, rejecting unexpected input, or filter it.

The other, better solution, is to disallow HTML input altogether, instead opting for an alternative markup system such as the popular [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/), used by websites such as Reddit.com and GitHub.

By suggesting the use of Regular Expressions for input validation, you are setting those you are educating on the "wrong track".

Comment: obviously you are correct. If you read my question you would see that I am not trying to protect against it and anything else you read into it were your own assumptions.

Comment: You preface your question by mentioning you are "teaching about XSS". By then asking about how to match a script element using regular expressions, it is not a poor inference to assume you are trying to protect against XSS this way. One should never, ever try to use regular expressions with HTML.

Comment: Disagreeing with you is not "trolling". You asked a question, and because the answer to it criticizes your premise, you are becoming rude. Teaching what cross-site scripting is does not require the use of regular expressions. Of all people, I should know. I ran HackThisSite.org for a time.